# Elasticsearch forward slash query string

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I have a big collection of files indexed by Elasticsearch. Besides other information, I've extracted all the ASCII strings from these files. The mapping for strings:

```
 ...
 "strings": {
            "type": "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
 },
 ...
```

This service is publicly exposed, so anyone can search for a specific string and ES should return all files that contains that string. Let's suppose a file contains the following string:

```
 Library/Application Support/MyApp/Users/Default/Logs
```

The problem is when I search for files that contains this kind of strings.

I've tried to use the following query, but it raises an **search_phase_execution_exception**:

```
 strings:*Support\\/MyApp*
```

How should I search for it?

I'm using elasticsearch-py (http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to connect to ES. A query looks like this

```
query_body = {
            "query": {
                      "query_string": {
                                       "query": "%s" % to_search
                      }
            }
}
data = es.search(index="files",
                       body=query_body)
```

, where **to_search** is the value of a POST parameter.

The django error:

```
RequestError at /search/
TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception')
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://----------/search/data=strings%3A*Support%5C%5C%2FMyApp*
Django Version: 1.8.5
Exception Type: RequestError
Exception Value:    
TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception')
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py in _raise_error, line 105
```

Also, the ES error:

```
RemoteTransportException[[Strong Guy][192.168.71.14:9300 [indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "strings:*Support\\\\/MyApp*"}}, "from": 0, "size": 18}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[Failed to parse query [strings:*Support\\/MyApp*]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse 'strings:*Support\\/MyApp*': Lexical error at line 1, column 26.

Encountered: <EOF> after : "/MyApp*"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 26.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/MyApp*"];
Caused by: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query": {"query_string": {"query": "strings:*Support\\\\/MyApp*"}}, "from": 0, "size": 18}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[Failed to parse query [strings
:*Support\\/MyApp*]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse 'strings:*Support\\/MyApp*': Lexical error at line 1, column 26.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/MyApp*"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 26
.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/MyApp*"];
```

Comment: If you're submitting the value through the browser it probably needs to be URL-encoded - on the server side just sending the raw value will work fine. Hard to pinpoint anything with no implementation details or code.

Comment: Please show the full query and also the full error message, it'll be easier to help you out.

Comment: I have a django project and I'm using this python module to connect to ES: http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/. Basically, I have a simple form, I get the query string from a post param and I'm using elasticsearch-py to get the results. Also, I tried this Chrome extension but I get the same results: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig.

Comment: What about the error? It will tell you exactly where it itches

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: What does the user input exactly? `strings:*Support\\/MyApp*`with the backslashes or is it something your Python app does?

Comment: The error from the ES log would be more useful than the Django one

Comment: The user inputs exactly this: strings:*Support\\/MyApp*

Comment: In any case, you'll probably need to add some cleanup code to sanitize the user input, the double backslash smells. A single one is sufficient, in my opinion.

Comment: So it should be something like: strings:*Support\/MyApp*? If I search for this, I don't get any results.

Comment: But you don't get any errors, which is better. Try a regexp query, like this: `strings:/.*Support\/MyApp.*/`, what do you get?

Comment: You are escaping using wrong slash. Try the following query "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "strings : *Support//MyApp*"
        }
    }, Escape using forward slash.

Comment: @VijayR. [reserved characters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) in a query string query are escaped with a single backslash, not a forward slash

Comment: @Val An exception: RemoteTransportException[[Strong Guy][192.168.71.14:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{
    "_source": ["md5"],
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "strings:/.*Support\/MyApp.*/"
        }
    }
}

Comment: My bad, try this: `strings:/.*Support\\/MyApp.*/`

Comment: @Val This doesn't raise any exception, but it also doesn't return any hit.

Comment: See my answer below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to POST this query, I do get results by adding `lowercase_expanded_terms` and setting it to false

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "strings:/.*Support\\/MyApp.*/",
      "lowercase_expanded_terms": false
    }
  }
}
```

Your original one also works

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "strings:*Support\\/MyApp*",
      "lowercase_expanded_terms": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No hits using this. :(

Comment: Then something is wrong in your problem statement, I'm using the same mapping, data and query.

Comment: Tested on django and on Sense Chrome extension. No results. Maybe because the index is "not_analyzed".

Comment: I've created the same mapping with `strings` being `not_analyzed` as well.

Comment: Are you sure about your sample file name?

Comment: Yes, I verified and it's how I said.

Comment: Tested on other ES database and it works. But what's the explanation? If I hardcode "lowercase_expanded_terms" to "false" how it will affect other queries?

Comment: Nice! `lowercase_expanded_terms` is only necessary if you detect a wildcard in the user input.